# python script printing to txt when startet manually but not at startup via rc.local on bootup

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, grovepi+

i am trying to get my raspberry pi to print data from external sensors to a display and save it to a .txt at the same time.

What i did works fine when launching the script in a shell via ssh. But that stops the script after closing the shell.

So i tried to put it in the rc.local file to launch it while booting. But that works only half way, as it shows the data on the display but it doesn't save it to a file.

```
import grovepi

from grovepi import *
from grove_rgb_lcd import *
from time import sleep, strftime
from math import isnan


#port definition
dht_sensor_port = 7 
dht_sensor_type = 0 
led_green = 5
led_red = 6
f = open("hwd.txt", "w")

#rgb display color
setRGB(0,255,0)

while True:
    try:
        [ temp,hum ] = dht(dht_sensor_port,dht_sensor_type)
        print("temp =", temp, "C\thumidity =", hum,"%")
        print("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),(temp,hum)), file=f)

        if isnan(temp) is True or isnan(hum) is True:
            raise TypeError('nan error')

        t = str(temp)
        h = str(hum)    
        
        setText_norefresh("Temp:" + t + "C\n" + "Humidity :" + h + "%")

        if hum < 40.0 or hum > 60.0:
            grovepi.digitalWrite(led_red,1)
            grovepi.digitalWrite(led_green,0)
        else:
            grovepi.digitalWrite(led_green,1)
            grovepi.digitalWrite(led_red, 0)

    except (IOError, TypeError) as e:
        print(str(e))
        setText("")

    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print(str(e))
        setText("")
        break

    sleep(1)

``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running an infinite loop, so you need to close the file stream to save changes into your file. If you run your script without the loop you can see that the changes are saved even without closing the steam and that's because it handles implicitly. So you need to open and close the file stream which can easily be done with the `with` keyword. I think the code below works fine for you.

```
import grovepi

from grovepi import *
from grove_rgb_lcd import *
from time import sleep, strftime
from math import isnan

# port definition
dht_sensor_port = 7
dht_sensor_type = 0
led_green = 5
led_red = 6

# rgb display color
setRGB(0, 255, 0)

while True:
    try:
        [temp, hum] = dht(dht_sensor_port, dht_sensor_type)
        print("temp =", temp, "C\thumidity =", hum, "%")
        with open("hwd.txt", "w") as f:
            print("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), (temp, hum)), file=f)

        if isnan(temp) is True or isnan(hum) is True:
            raise TypeError('nan error')

        t = str(temp)
        h = str(hum)

        setText_norefresh("Temp:" + t + "C\n" + "Humidity :" + h + "%")

        if hum < 40.0 or hum > 60.0:
            grovepi.digitalWrite(led_red, 1)
            grovepi.digitalWrite(led_green, 0)
        else:
            grovepi.digitalWrite(led_green, 1)
            grovepi.digitalWrite(led_red, 0)

    except (IOError, TypeError) as e:
        print(str(e))
        setText("")

    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print(str(e))
        setText("")
        break

    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Still the same problem, it runs and data is displayed on the lcd but there is no .txt file being generated(or data beeing saved if the file already exists) when started on bootup, but works fine when manually initiated via ssh shell.

Comment: Does the data keep updated on the display? Maybe the script fails due to a permission error or something else. Try adding  `except Exception as e` and print error on the display. Or maybe you're looking for your file in the wrong directory.

Comment: the display works fine, the only problem is logging the data to the txt. I heard there are problems with running python scripts in the background which is basically what rc.local does. Would make sense as it works when startet manually. I will try finding out more over the weekend as iam overloaded with work right now. Thank you very much for your effort so far, already helped me alot. Will send an update when i know more.